# SVG редактор с коллекцией готовых объектов(фигур, изображений)?

Tags: svg

Какие есть svg редакторы **не** под web, а для windows.

Где бы уже была большая коллекция разных фигур, изображений аналогично фотошопу?
Желательно бесплатный, быстрый, не перегруженный лишним функционалом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inkscape](http://habrahabr.ru/post/271559/) - довольно неплохой векторный редактор, особенно после последнего обновления.